# What conventions does IPOPT use to construct its Lagrangian?

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

I am using IPOPT via Pyomo (the AMPL interface) to solve a simple problem and am trying to validate that the primal Lagrangian gradient is zero at the solution. I'm running the following script, in which I construct what I would expect to be the gradient of the Lagrangian with respect to primal variables.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.common.collections import ComponentMap

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.ipopt_zL_out = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT)
m.ipopt_zU_out = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT)
m.ipopt_zL_in = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.EXPORT)
m.ipopt_zU_in = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.EXPORT)
m.dual = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT)

m.v1 = pyo.Var(initialize=-2.0)
m.v2 = pyo.Var(initialize=2.0)
m.v3 = pyo.Var(initialize=2.0)

m.v1.setlb(-10.0)
m.v2.setlb(1.5)
m.v1.setub(-1.0)
m.v2.setub(10.0)

m.eq_con = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.v1*m.v2*m.v3 - 2.0 == 0)

obj_factor = 1 
m.obj = pyo.Objective(
        expr=obj_factor*(m.v1**2 + m.v2**2 + m.v3**2),
        sense=pyo.minimize,
        )

solver = pyo.SolverFactory("ipopt")
solver.solve(m, tee=True)

grad_lag_map = ComponentMap()
grad_lag_map[m.v1] = ( 
        (obj_factor*2*m.v1) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v2*m.v3 +
        m.ipopt_zL_out[m.v1] + m.ipopt_zU_out[m.v1]
        )
grad_lag_map[m.v2] = ( 
        (obj_factor*2*m.v2) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v1*m.v3 +
        m.ipopt_zL_out[m.v2] + m.ipopt_zU_out[m.v2]
        )
grad_lag_map[m.v3] = ( 
        (obj_factor*2*m.v3) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v1*m.v2
        )

for var, expr in grad_lag_map.items():
    print(var.name, pyo.value(expr))
```

According to this, however, the gradient of the Lagrangian is not zero when constructed in this way. I can get the gradient of the Lagrangian to be zero by using the following lines to construct `grad_lag_map`

```py
grad_lag_map[m.v1] = (
        -(obj_factor*2*m.v1) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v2*m.v3 +
        m.ipopt_zL_out[m.v1] + m.ipopt_zU_out[m.v1]
        )
grad_lag_map[m.v2] = (
        -(obj_factor*2*m.v2) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v1*m.v3 +
        m.ipopt_zL_out[m.v2] + m.ipopt_zU_out[m.v2]
        )
grad_lag_map[m.v3] = (
        -(obj_factor*2*m.v3) + m.dual[m.eq_con]*m.v1*m.v2
        )
```

With a minus sign in front of the objective gradient, the gradient of the Lagrangian is zero. This is surprising to me. I would not expect to see this factor of -1 for minimization problems. Can anybody confirm whether IPOPT constructs its Lagrangian with this -1 factor for minimization problems, or whether this is the artifact of some other convention I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Gradient of the Lagrangian w.r.t. x computed in Ipopt (https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/2b1a2f9a60fb3f8426b47edbe3b3520c7335d201/src/Algorithm/IpIpoptCalculatedQuantities.cpp#L2018-L2023):

```c
tmp->Copy(*curr_grad_f());
tmp->AddTwoVectors(1., *curr_jac_cT_times_curr_y_c(), 1., *curr_jac_dT_times_curr_y_d(), 1.);
ip_nlp_->Px_L()->MultVector(-1., *z_L, 1., *tmp);
ip_nlp_->Px_U()->MultVector(1., *z_U, 1., *tmp);
```

This corresponds to an Ipopt-internal representation of a NLP, which has the form

```
min  f(x)                     dual vars:
s.t. c(x) = 0,                y_c
     d(x) - s = 0,            y_d
     d_L <= s <= d_U,         v_L, v_U
     x_L <= x <= x_U          z_L, z_U
```

The Lagragian for Ipopt is then

```
f(x) + y_c c(x) + y_d (d(x) - s) + v_L (d_L-s) + v_U (s-d_U) + z_L (x_L-x) + z_U (x-x_U)
```

and the gradient w.r.t. x is thus

```
f'(x) + y_c c'(x) + y_d d'(x) - z_L + z_U
```

The NLP that is used by most Ipopt interfaces is

```
min  f(x)                   duals:
s.t. g_L <= g(x) <= g_U     lambda
     x_L <= x <= x_U        z_L, z_U
```

The Gradient of the Lagrangian would be

```
f'(x) + lambda g'(x) - z_L + z_U
```

In your code, you have a wrong sign for z_L.